# AltBeacon issue after adding Parse server push notification

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

My application was working ok, but after i added the push notifications from parse server, i started getting an error when the app is launched (see message below), while the app open and work ok, when i close the app the same is not doing the background search and notification.

```
09-30 17:22:12.006 10338-10349/br.com.inconnet.inbeacon E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
                                                              java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                                                  at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:571)
                                                                  at android.os.Message.-wrap0(Message.java)
                                                                  at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:527)
                                                                  at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:525)
                                                                  at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51)
                                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
                                                                  at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:571) 
                                                                  at android.os.Message.-wrap0(Message.java) 
                                                                  at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:527) 
                                                                  at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:525) 
                                                                  at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51) 
                                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

if i remove the following information from my AndroidManifest.xml, the app works ok again.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:xxxxxx" />
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="br.com.inconnet.inbeacon" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

How can i make both work thogeter?

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem has been reported by folks who are bundling their apps with certain other services and the Android Beacon Library.  There is no known fix or even a fully understood cause.   You can read more about the issue here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/306

One theory is that bundling some services with your app somehow forces other services in the app to run in a separate process, something the Android Beacon Library does not support.

If you have proguard settings enabled, you may want to try disabling them to see if this makes the problem go away.